# How to add parallel processing to a spring-batch Step?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("jobname")
        .listener(..)
        .reader(..)
        .processor(..)
        .writer(..)
        .build();
}
```

The `reader` is a custom threadsafe reader fetching data from a webservice by pagination. The state is maintained threadsafe. The `writer` is a simple `JpaItemWriter`.

Now I'd like to run the reader `Step` multithreaded. Because the webservice is very slow, the reader is the bottleneck, and I could maybe read 4 pages of the webservice in parallel.

But if I add `.taskExecutor(new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor())` to the step, I can only add a `Tasklet` furthermore, but not reader, processor or writer.

So the question is: how can I add parallel processing to the above step, without having to use a `Tasklet`?

Comment: you can try partitioning in spring batch and see if it fits your use case

Comment: I think the problem is the order of and the used chained methods. Try this one ..get ().chunk ().reader ().processor ().writer ().faulttolerant ().taskececutor().biuild (); I am on vacation at the moment, therefore I don't have access to my code. But I remember having issues with that.

Comment: A step consists of reader , processor and writer. It looks you are asking to parallelize only step reader but not whole step. Do I read your question correctly? Also, if my guess is correct to parallelize only step reader and not whole step and you say its a custom reader so I think you need to write multi threaded code inside step reader to fetch data from multiple threads.